# working in jsfiddle but not in browser

Tags: jquery, html

it is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/963/ but when loading on browser one functionality is not working i.e. when i am dragging (a),(b),(c),(d) to textbox the values are not getting stored as in fiddle.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-2.css" /> 

 <style>

.not_attempted {color:red; font-weight:700;}
  .correct {color:green; font-weight:700;}
  .incorrect {color:red; font-weight:700;}

 </style>
 </head>
    <body>
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header">
<div class="header1">
<div class="heading1">Inside Our Earth</div>
<div class="heading2">How to match?</div>
<div class="heading3">How to match?</div>
</div>

<div class="header2"></div>

</div><!--header closed-->
<div class="front_page">
<div class="fp1"><h1>Instruction</h1></div>

 <div class="fp2"><h2>Match Column <b style="color:#000;">A</b> with Coloumn <b
 style="color:#000;">B</b> by dragging given letters.</h2></div>
 <div class="fp3"><h2>After you have attempted answering all questions, click on the <b 
 style="color:#B30000;">"Submit"</b> button to know the Score</h2></div>
 <input type="button" class="continue" value="Continue"/> 
 <div class="ffooter"><b style="position:absolute;margin-left:680px; margin-
 top:40px;">Copyright @ 2014 Educo International.inc</b></div>
 </div><!--front_page closed-->
  <div id="element_to_pop_up">
 <div class="e1">How to match?</div>
 <div class="e2">
 <ul><li><span>Take the mouse on the top of the button in column <b>B</b>.</span></li>
 <li><span>When mouse become a hand click and drag.</span></li>
 <li><span>Place it on the appropriate box in the left column.</span></li>
 </ul>
 </div> 

   </div>
<div class="container">
<div class="container_top"></div>
<div class="cntt1">Match Column <b style="color:#000;">A</b> with Coloumn <b 
   style="color:#000;">B</b> by dragging given letters.</div>
<div class="cntt2">Column (A)</div>
<div class="cntt3">Column (B)</div>
<div class="cntt4"></div>
<div class="cntt5"></div>
<input type="button" class="new_set" value="New Set" />
<input type="button" class="done" value="Done" />
<input type="button" class="soln" value="Solution"  disabled="true"/>
<input type="button" class="reset" value="Reset all"/>
<div class="cnt1"></div>
<div class="cnt2"></div>
<div class="cnt3"></div>
<div class="cnt4"></div>
<div class="cnt5"></div>
<div class="cnt6"></div>
<div class="cnt7"></div>
<div class="cnt8"></div>
 <div class="ans_set1">
<input type="text" maxlength="10" value="" class="ans_set1_1" />
<br><input type="text"  maxlength="10" class="ans_set1_2" />
<br><input type="text" maxlength="0" class="ans_set1_3" />
<br><input type="text" maxlength="0" class="ans_set1_4" />
</div>
<div class="ans_set2">
<input type="text" maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_1" />
<br><input type="text"  maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_2" />
<br><input type="text" maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_3" />
<br><input type="text" maxlength="10" class="ans_set2_4" />
</div>
<div class="abcd">
<div class="a" id="draggable"><b>(a)</b></div>
<div class="b" id="draggable"><b>(b)</b></div>
<div class="c" id="draggable"><b>(c)</b></div>
<div class="d" id="draggable"><b>(d)</b></div>
</div>

</div><!--container closed-->
<div class="footer"><b style="position:absolute;margin-left:680px; margin-
 top:40px;">Copyright @ 2014 Educo International.inc</b>
</div><!--footer closed-->
</div><!--wrapper closed-->


<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui1.js"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript">


 var array_i = new Array();
  array_i [0] = {question : "Sima "  ,answer:"5"};

  array_i [1] = {question : "Rocks "  ,answer:"6"};

  array_i [2] = {question : "Mineral "  ,answer:"13"};

   array_i [3] = {question : "Shale "  ,answer:"1"};

  array_i [4] = {question : "Hydrosphere "  ,answer:"24"};

   array_i [5] = {question : "Environment "  ,answer:"1"};

  array_i [6] = {question : "Biosphere "  ,answer:"23"};

  array_i [7] = {question : "Atmosphere "  ,answer:"1"};



 var array_j = new Array();
  array_j [0] = {answer:"Changes into Slate"};

  array_j [1] = {answer:"the materials of the Earth's  crust "};

  array_j [2] = {answer:"have definite chemical composition"};

   array_j [3] = {answer:"made up of Silica and Magnesium"};

  array_j [4] = {answer:"Our surroundings"};

   array_j [5] = {answer:"Domain of water"};

  array_j [6] = {answer:"Blanket of air which surrounds the Earth"};

  array_j [7] = {answer:"Narrow zone where land,water and air interact"};                













 i=0
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {

    $(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable({
        revert: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });
    $(".ans_set1_1,.ans_set1_2,.ans_set1_3,.ans_set1_4").droppable({
        accept: ".a,.b,.c,.d",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
              var $answer=ui.draggable;
              var $input=$(event.target);

              var val=$answer.text();

              $input.val(val);

        }
    });
 });



    $('.new_set').click(function() {

        $('.cnt1,.cnt2,.cnt3,.cnt4,.cnt5,.cnt6,.cnt7,.cnt8').empty();

        i=i+4
        if(i==8)
        {
            i=0;

        }

        $(".cnt1").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; 
      color:#FF0080'>"+["("]+[i+1]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i]
    ['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
$(".cnt2").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+
 ["("]+[i+2]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i+1]['question']+"<span 
  class='label3'></span></p>");
$(".cnt3").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+
["("]+[i+3]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i+2]['question']+"<span 
class='label3'></span></p>");
$(".cnt4").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+
["("]+[i+4]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i+3]['question']+"<span 
class='label3'></span></p>");
$(".cnt5").append("<b >"+array_j[i]['answer']+"</b>");
$(".cnt6").append("<b>"+array_j[i+1]['answer']+"</b>");
$(".cnt7").append("<b>"+array_j[i+2]['answer']+"</b>");
$(".cnt8").append("<b>"+array_j[i+3]['answer']+"</b>");
          if(i==0)
         {
        $('.ans_set1').show();
         $('.ans_set2').hide();
        }
        if(i==4)
        {
        $('.ans_set2').show();
         $('.ans_set1').hide();
          }

    });

    $('.continue').click(function() {


     $('.heading2,.front_page').hide()
    $('.heading3,.container,.footer').show()
    $(".cnt1").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+
   ["("]+[i+1]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+array_i[i]['question']+"
   </b>"+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
$(".cnt2").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+
 ["("]+[i+2]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+ array_i[i+1]
['question']+"<span class='label3'></span></p>");
$(".cnt3").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+
["("]+[i+3]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+ array_i[i+2]['question']+"<span 
class='label3'></span></p>");
$(".cnt4").append("<p>"+"<b style='font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive; color:#FF0080'>"+
["("]+[i+4]+[")."]+"</b>"+ "<b style='margin-left:50px;'>"+ array_i[i+3]       
['question']+"<span        class='label3'></span></p>");
  $(".cnt5").append("<b>"+array_j[i]['answer']+"</b>");
 $(".cnt6").append("<b>"+array_j[i+1]['answer']+"</b>");
 $(".cnt7").append("<b>"+array_j[i+2]['answer']+"</b>");
   $(".cnt8").append("<b>"+array_j[i+3]['answer']+"</b>");
    });
    $ ('.heading3').mouseover(function() {
            $(".heading3").css({"color":"yellow",'font-size' : '34px'})
    $(this).click(function() {

    $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
     });(jQuery);

    $(this).mouseout(function() {
            $(".heading3").css({"color":"#FFF",'font-size' : '26px'});


    });
    });






 });'



 </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you selecting jquery in the top left of the jsfiddle window ?

Comment: yes on the top left both jquery and jquery ui

Comment: @Billy there is jQuery 1.4.2 both in fiddle and in presented HTML.

Comment: @NitishDhawan what is `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui1.js"></script>`?

Comment: i have saved it locally  with this name

Comment: Saved what? jQuery UI? Then what is `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` in previous line?

Comment: i have added to versions of ui

Comment: @NitishDhawan I doubt that you can use two versions of jQuery UI. Choose one.

Comment: which version u suggest me to choose for drag and drop because it is not working properly in many version

Comment: @NitishDhawan you use jQuery UI 1.8.4 in JSFiddle - it will be logical to use jQuery UI 1.8.4 on site as well.

Comment: still facing same problem

Comment: @NitishDhawan by the way, do you have any errors in console?

Comment: no it is working fine just the drop is not working as i want it to in browser but in fiddle it is working.

Comment: when testing your code appears following error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal